# Angular: queryParams does not work when updating url programmatically

Tags: angular, routes, query-string

When I update the url's query params programmtically like so:

```
window.history.pushState({}, '', 'http://localhost:4200/#/some/url?param=value');
```

and then try to get this param using `ActivatedRoute` service like this:

```
let params = this._activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParams;
console.log(params);
```

I get this result:

```
{param: ''} // should be {param: 'value'}
```

can someone explain this behavior ? thanks in advance.

**My actual code:**

```
let url = LocationManager.addParam({key: 'param', value: 'value'});
window.history.pushState({}, '', url);
this._activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(queryParams => {
     console.log({queryParams});
});
```

a service I have created:

```
export class LocationManager{

    /**
     * Get value of param
     * @param param 
     * @returns value
     */
    static param(param){
        return this.params()[param];
    }

    /**
     * add param to url
     * @param param 
     * @returns url
     */
    static addParam(param: {key: string, value: string}){
        let params = this.params();
        params[param.key] = param.value;
        return this.buildURL(params);
    }

    /**
     * Return query params of url
     */
    static params(){
        let params = {};
        let url = window.location.href;

        if(url.includes('?')){
            let paramsString = url.split('?')[1];
            let p = paramsString.split('&');

            p.forEach((item) => {
                let kv = item.split('=');
                params[kv[0]] = kv[1];
            });
        }

        return params;
    }

    /**
     * Build url from query params
     * @param params 
     */
    static buildURL(params: {}){
        let array = [];
        for(let key in params){
            array.push(`${key}=${params[key]}`);
        }
        let paramsString = array.join('&');
        let url = window.location.href;
        let splietdURL = url.split('?');
        return `${splietdURL[0]}?${paramsString}`;
    }
}
```

Comment: Apparently, "pushState doesn't trigger any events so it's not possible to intercept it." Source: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13396

Answer (score 2):

The value isn't updating, because the snapshot of the route is taken at the first load of the component. The value will only be calculated for the first load of the component and won’t change unless you reload the page.

Luckily you can subscribe to the query params directly and that should help your use case:

```
this.activeRoute.queryParams.subscribe(queryParams => {
        // Do something with the query params
    });
```

Comment: Would you please share your actual component code instead of the little snippets?